# Cannot iterate through a Spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I want to iterate through an RDD in Spark Repl, but it does not seem to work

```
case class Person(age: Long, name: String)

val df = Seq(Person(24, "pedro"), Person(22, "fritz")).toDF()

val myWholeRDD : RDD[Row] = df.select("*").rdd

myWholeRDD.foreach(println)
```

Foreach is a function in RDD, so what is the issue?

Here is the exception that I get

> ERROR ExecutorClassLoader: Failed to check existence of class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Object on REPL class server
>   at spark://10.203.125.99:61974/classes java.io.IOException: Failed to
>   connect to /10.203.125.99:61974 at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
>   at

Comment: So what is the issue ? what did not work ?

Comment: I was getting this error before

Comment: [Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]18/04/25 00:13:44 ERROR ExecutorClassLoader: Failed to check existence of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Object on REPL class server at spark://10.203.125.99:61974/classes
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.203.125.99:61974
 at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
 at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
 at

Comment: local mode and in spark repl 2.2.0

Comment: can you try starting `spark-shell` with `spark-shell --master local[*]`

Comment: It works fine now thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error log says it could not connect to the master

> Failed to connect to /10.203.125.99:61974 at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)

If you are trying to run the spark-shell on local you can start spark-shell as

```
spark-shell --master local[*]
```

Hope this helps !